# Programing a Mini 05 without a USB-to-serial converter

Tags: programming, usb, arduino-mini

I have an Arduino Mini 05 clone [Wattuino](http://www.watterott.com/de/Wattuino-pro-mini-5V-16MHz), an [Elegoo Mega](https://www.amazon.de/Elegoo-Mikrocontroller-ATmega2560-ATMEGA16U2-Kompatibel/dp/B01MA5BLQI), a [Powerboost 1000c](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465), but not access to a USB-to-serial converter. Is there any way to program the Arduino Mini with these devices?

I tried to search it but they only mention using an Arduino uno as the chip can be put out of the board. [Discusion](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=104135.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mega. The only reason for "removing the chip from the board" is to disable it so it doesn't respond to the serial data - you can also disable it by just connecting the RESET pin to GND.